# Relative link to local file not clickable when generating pdf with puppeteer

Tags: html, typescript, pdf, puppeteer

I'm generating some pdfs with puppeteer, and it works well.
However, I want to add (relative) links into the generated pdfs to other local files that are in the same directory.

I was able to generate such pdfs with word so I know it is doable, but I don't know what's missing in my code.

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

export async function genPdf(outputFile: string) {
    const htmlContent = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <p><a href=\"./linktofile.pdf\">open pdf file</a></p>
        </body>
        </html>
    `;

    // Launch a headless browser with puppeteer
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: "new" });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    // Set the HTML content of the page
    await page.setContent(htmlContent);

    // Generate PDF from the HTML content
    await page.pdf({
        path: outputFile,
        format: 'A4',
    });

    // Close the browser
    await browser.close();
}
```

Comment: Why are you escaping quotes inside the backticks? Maybe just fix the quotes and it will work?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher it does not really matter, tried without, it gives the same result